# How do I get the aws account id from a aws_iam_user in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to add the following policy to a iam user using terraform. How do I add the account ID in the policy of the upload_user_user?

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "product_upload_user" {
  name = "cc-${terraform.workspace}-product-upload-user"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "allow_upload" {
  user   = aws_iam_user.product_upload_user.name
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_upload.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_upload" {

  statement {
    sid       = "STSToken"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["sts:GetFederationToken"]
    # resources = ["arn:aws:sts::${aws_iam_user.product_upload_user.<account_id>}:federated-user/S3UploadWebToken"]
  }
}
```

Trying to implement the policy from this tutorial: https://next-s3-upload.codingvalue.com/setup

Answer (score 5):

You can use the the Terraform data resource, [aws_caller_identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/caller_identity). The data resource has an `account_id` attribute that can be exported. This also prevents hard coding the account id into your code. I've added the addition to your code that can be tested.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "product_upload_user" {
  name = "cc-${terraform.workspace}-product-upload-user"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy" "allow_upload" {
  user   = aws_iam_user.product_upload_user.name
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_upload.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_upload" {
  statement {
    sid       = "STSToken"
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["sts:GetFederationToken"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:sts::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:federated-user/S3UploadWebToken"]
  }
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
```